# Does TFS 2012 have any REST API

Tags: rest

I am trying to read some information from TFS 2012 REST API's so are there any REST API's to get the info from TFS

Comment: There is OData for getting data out of TFS, that can be called over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, the first release of 1.0 API's (that too undocumented started with TFS 2013). This is the official documented release for API versions.

[image]

Major API version releases align with Team Foundation Server RTM releases. For example, the 3.0 API set was introduced with Team Foundation Server 2017.

A small number of undocumented version 1.0 APIs existed in Team Foundation Server 2013, but are not supported.

Official Visual Studio documentation for API's [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics).